# upload image in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with the upload of some images. So...I have the admin side in which I click on the "Add image" button and I begin adding the images. When I begin adding them the image is not shown so that I can see it. And when I click save the images should save to a certain location. My question is: why can't I see my images after I click the Add image button? and why aren't the pictures being saved in the path that I specify?
Thanks a lot!
I also added some code here:
This is in my controller:

```
public function showcase_image(){
    try{
                $config['upload_path'] = './resources/media/showcase/image/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg|flv|mp3|wav';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->do_upload('add_image');
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $w = 720;
        $h = 425;

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '';
        $config['width'] = $w;
        $config['height'] = $h;


        $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
        if($data['image_width']<425 && $data['image_height']<425){
        }else{
            $this->image_lib->resize();
        }
        $file = $data['file_name'];

        echo json_encode(array("error"=>false,"msg"=>"success","file"=>$file,"dir"=>"image"));
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        echo json_encode(array("error"=>true,"msg"=>$e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

This is in my model:

```
public function getShowcases(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM showcase ORDER BY showcase_id DESC");
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }

    public function getImagesShowcase($idShowcase){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM showcase_gallery WHERE showcase_gallery_project_id='".$idShowcase."' AND showcase_gallery_type='image' ORDER BY showcase_gallery_index ASC");
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

And on the view side I have some ajax:

```
 function ajaxFileUploadImage(){
    $("#loading")
        .ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxComplete(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    $.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url:'<?=site_url('ajaxadmin/showcase_image')?>',
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'add_image',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{},
            success: function (data, status)
            {
                //jQuery('.thumb_file').attr('src','<?=base_url()?>resources/media/our_work/thumb/'+data.file);
                //jQuery('input[name=thumb]').val(data.file);
                var image = ' \
                <div class="list" style="float:left;position:relative;margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;"> \
                    <div class="description_img"> \
                        <div class="delete_img"></div> \
                    </div> \
                    <img height="100" src="<?=base_url()?>resources/media/showcase/image/'+data.file+'" style="z-index: 0; position: relative;"/> \
                    <div class="move_arrows"> \
                        <div class="move_on_left"></div> \
                        <div class="move_on_right"></div> \
                    </div> \
                    <input type="hidden" name="image_filename[]" class="image_filename" value="'+data.file+'"/> \
                </div> \
                ';
                jQuery('#showcase_image').append(jQuery(image));
            },
            error: function (data, status, e){
                jQuery('.response_mes').html('<span class="red">* please try again later!</span>');
            }
        }
    )
    return false;
}
```

I hope this code will be useful and maybe if someone has a soultion would be great.:D

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the jQuery AjaxFileUpload plugin found [here](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) which uses the "iFrame" upload trick. You should try using [qqFileUploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) from valums which uses pure AJAX to upload if the browser supports it and falls back on iFrame if necessary. I believe it is a superior way to upload via AJAX and will be easier to implement.

Comment: but with ajaxfileupload can't I fix this problem? the thing is that in one part where I have to upload projects it works perfectly and when I try to load photos for showcase it doesn't. i tryed copying the code from one part to the other but I got the same results

Comment: I agree that you should be able to get it to work using your existing codebase. Have you inspected the contents of your $_POST array that is coming into CodeIgniter to be certain that all the file upload details are correct?

Answer (score 0):

example of how to upload image using ajax. i think this will help you out.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#upfile1").click(function () {
    $("#file1").trigger('click');
  });

  var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]'); 
  input.onchange = function () {
  var file_data = $("#file1").prop("files")[0]; // Getting the properties of file from file field
   var form_data = new FormData(); // Creating object of FormData class   
   form_data.append("file", file_data)
   var filevalue = $("#file1").val();
   console.log(form_data);

    $.ajax({
      url:'index.php/welcome/uploadImage',
      type:'POST',
      data : form_data,
      cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
      success:function( data )
      {
       console.log(data);
      },
      error:function( error ){
       console.log(error);
      }
    }); 
   }
});

<input type="file" id="file1" name="image" value=""  accept="image/*" capture style="display:none"/>
<img src="http://macgroup.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/iphone-camera-icon-150x150.jpg" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" />
```